# Sends eth to arbitrary user (Slither warning)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

How do I resolve Slither warning about the low level call in the following method:

```
 // A proposer calls function and if address has an allowance, recieves ETH in return.
    function getPayout(address payable addressOfProposer)
        public
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Get the available allowance first amd store in uint256.
        uint256 allowanceAvailable = _payoutTotals[addressOfProposer];
        require(allowanceAvailable > 0, "You do not have any funds available.");

        _decreasePayout(addressOfProposer, allowanceAvailable);

        (bool sent, ) = addressOfProposer.call{value: allowanceAvailable}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send ether");

     // console.log("transfer success");
        emit Withdraw(addressOfProposer, allowanceAvailable);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `//slither-disable-next-line DETECTOR_NAME`:

```
// A proposer calls function and if address has an allowance, recieves ETH in return.
    function getPayout(address payable addressOfProposer)
        public
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Get the available allowance first amd store in uint256.
        uint256 allowanceAvailable = _payoutTotals[addressOfProposer];
        require(allowanceAvailable > 0, "You do not have any funds available.");

        _decreasePayout(addressOfProposer, allowanceAvailable);

        //slither-disable-next-line unchecked-lowlevel
        (bool sent, ) = addressOfProposer.call{value: allowanceAvailable}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send ether");

     // console.log("transfer success");
        emit Withdraw(addressOfProposer, allowanceAvailable);
        return true;
    }
```

It's interesting that it gives an unchecked low-level call warning, however, given that it does appear to be checked.

Comment: This does not seem to toggle mine off, either with unchecked-lowlevel or arbitrary-send-eth https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/1225

Comment: Update to last comment: unchecked-lowlevel detector is where "The return value of a low-level call is not checked." (per the docs), but he's checking it here with (bool sent, ). 

When I use //slither-disable-next-line arbitrary-send-eth, which I believe is the one, it still fails https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/1225

Comment: 2nd update: 

the solution is
//slither-disable-next-line arbitrary-send
per https://github.com/crytic/slither/blob/master/README.md